# What do these parameters of Global Offensive's Bot Profile mean?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

What do these parameters in the Counter-Strike: Global Offensive's `BotProfile.db` mean?

```
LookAngleMaxAccelNormal = 2000.0
LookAngleStiffnessNormal = 100.0
LookAngleDampingNormal = 25.0
LookAngleMaxAccelAttacking = 3000.0
LookAngleStiffnessAttacking = 150.0
LookAngleDampingAttacking = 30.0
```

Also, what are these values? Do they have any real significance, like `ReactionTime` and `AttackDelay` which have values in seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://steamcommunity.com/groups/p_nm/discussions/0/522730075468755846/

[...]

Next on the list are looking around and forward parameters. Let's start from a basic explanation, that a bot has a head with a spring/damper system instead of his neck - it is just like a suspension in a car. If you hit a bump, the wheel will go up with certain accelaration, but how quickly a body of the car reacts and goes up depends on the spring. And we all know what damper is for, don't we? To damp oscillations. And this is exactly how it works with bots. The bottom (base) of their neck (a wheel in the car from above example), will move to the new intended position (regarding center of their field of vision angles) when so commanded, with a defined acceleration:

LookAngleMaxAccelNormal = 3000.0 (when not engaged)

LookAngleMaxAccelAttacking = 4500.0 (when engaged)

But how quickly bot's head (body of the car from the example above) follows and when and how it reaches the new intended position depends on these spring... :

LookAngleStiffnessNormal = 150.0 (strenght of the spring when not engaged)

LookAngleStiffnessAttacking = 500.0 (strenght of the spring when engaged)

... and damper parameters:

LookAngleDampingNormal = 30.0 (damping effect when not engaged)

LookAngleDampingAttacking = 40.0 (damping effect when engaged)

Note, that If a bot is hit by bullets in his head (and or body) may deviate from the intended position (and center of field of vision angles) and the about parameters define how quikly head returns to intended position and aiming starts. The damping should be set to minimum allowing for avoidance of oscillations. If it is set too high it make the bot head movements slower.

The best way to learn the optimal values is to play with above given LookAngle values. For the beginnig, to see how it works, you may wish to change one LookAngle parameter (for example LookAngleDampingNormal and/or LookAngleDampingAttacking) by factor or 10. In this case try how it works with a very small damping effect like 1, 2 or 5.

Those parameters are global - default for all bots - you can not make them individual for each bot or template.

[...]